# Derived table dependency

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When you join a table with a derived table, can the derived table query refer to columns from the other table in the join, and why?

Example :

```
SELECT
  cr.CountryRegionCode,
  cr.Name [Country Name],
  crc.CurrencyCode
Currency cr 
INNER JOIN 
     ( -- there are 109 currency codes in CountryRegionCurrency
       SELECT
         [CountryRegionCode],
         [CurrencyCode],
         [ModifiedDate]
       FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[Sales].[CountryRegionCurrency]
     ) crc ON cr.CountryRegionCode = crc.CountryRegionCode
```

Can the derived table query CRC refer to the columns of Currency ?

Comment: Post SQL with an example of what you mean. In fact then just execute it to answer your own question

Comment: No, it can't. By definition.

Comment: @jarlh can I have an example?

Comment: A derived table referenced by an APPLY can contain outer columns though

Comment: Example of what you can't do?

Comment: Looks like you have more than one account then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A derived table that is part of a `JOIN` cannot reference objects outside of the subquery's scope. A derived table that is part of an `APPLY` *can* reference columns outside of the subquery's scope.

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA A
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT *
                 FROM TableB sq
                 WHERE A.ID = sq.A_ID) B;
```

This will fail, due to the object `A` not being defined with the scope of the subquery. The correct syntax for the above query would be this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA A
     INNER JOIN (SELECT *
                 FROM TableB sq) B ON A.ID = B.A_ID;
```

On the other hand, if you were to use `APPLY` you *could* reference columns outside of the subquery's scope:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA A
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT *
                  FROM TableB sq
                  WHERE A.ID = sq.A_ID) B;
```

Edit: Not specific to the question, but it's worth noting that within a subquery if a column is not quantified then the column will always be assumed to reference the table in the subquery first. Let's assume, for example, that the columns to `JOIN` on are actually `A.ID` and `B.ID`. If you were therefore to do the below, it would work:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA A
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT *
                 FROM TableB sq
                 WHERE ID = ID) B;
```

That's because the `WHERE` might as well be `WHERE B.ID = B.ID` and `B.ID` is always going to equal the value of itself unless it has the value `NULL`.

It's therefore incredibly important to *always* quantify your columns.